# List of all different data license types and their respective restrictions?

Tags: licensing

I was hoping someone knew where I could get a master list of licences commonly used for datasets and the restrictions that each license imposes. Something like

```
{
    "Public Domain": {
        "commerically_available": True,
        "required_attribution": False
    },
    "CC-0": {
        "commerically_available": True,
        "required_attribution": False
    },
    "PDDL": {
        "commerically_available": True,
        "required_attribution": False
    },
    "CC-BY": {
        "commerically_available": True,
        "required_attribution": True
    },
}
```

etc. I've done some searching but haven't found anything structured, just web pages like this (https://help.data.world/hc/en-us/articles/115006114287-Common-license-types-for-datasets) which are helpful but still need to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was unable to find what I was looking for I ended up compiling the list myself and made it available as a public gist on github: https://gist.github.com/jhallard/2d26452b391908c607280d69b0462a5a

let me know if anything there is incorrect and feel free to add to it if a license in question is missing